# Can't use FTP to update plugin/upgrade wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I've been struggling with this wordpress FTP issue for the past 3 hour. When trying to update a plugin or wordpress it self it always gives me an error:

```
ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.
```

Things that I've done so far:
1. I've sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/blog
2. I've changed the permission of /var/www/blog to www-data
3. I've configured the following in my wp-config.php:

```
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', '54.251.103.225' );
```

I can try to ftp using the username and password above using FileZilla just fine with no issues.I've also tried changing the permission of the blog folder to the 'username' above, no luck. I've also changed the following:

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=14000
pasv_max_port=14050
port_enable=YES

pasv_address='my ip address'
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
```

to my vsftpd.conf, restarted it but no luck. Any ideas on what to do next? Also tried the plugin SSH SFTP Updater Support with no luck

Comment: Have you tried the domain name instead of ip?

Comment: I assume that you have changed user and group permissions... so it sounds like it might be one of my favorite GOTCHAS. It you're on AWS your IP may have changed invalidating the security group.

Comment: @stink so how do I fix this user and group permissions

Comment: If you have access to the AWS Dashboard go to EC2 check the name of the security group associated with the instance. On the left side of the page click Security Groups. Add your IP address for SSH(22) and FTP(21).

Comment: Apache needs to own or group own the root blog directory to be able to upload files via WordPress. That's equally as likely.

Comment: @stink I am using nginx by the way, oh and the blog owner is already www-data, which is what nginx is running as

Comment: @adit Are you on AWS... Did you try adding your IP to the 'Security Group'?

Comment: @stink yes I am on AWS, and the IP I put in there is 0.0.0.0, which essentially means all IP

Comment: @adit I'm running Apache... Apache group owns and user owns the directory where my site lives. If I want to SFTP something I have to change the ownership of the directory (var/www/http/wp-content/plugins) to ec2-user then do the upload. However, even if I don't change the ownership directory I can still connect. So that makes me think that the problem happens without file ownership being an issue. 

Just to confirm.
**You added your KeyFile to FileZilla > Settings > Connection > SFTP and in FileZilla > Site Manager > Authentication = Normal and FileZilla > Site Manager > User = ec2-user**

Comment: I ran out of characters... I know you can connect via FTP. I'm just trying to let you know how my configuration works so that maybe it can tip you off to something.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is not related but I ended up here and it might help others.

I had the same problem, I found a number of solutions in various forums, none of which helped. My credentials were OK but they were being rejected; they worked in Filezilla.

Somewhere I found a reference to a small plugin called '[SSH SFTP Updater Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/)', which fixed my problem. After installing this the option for SFTP is added and you can choose SSH2 when being challenged for the FTP login details.

Choose SSH2 at the bottom; and I didn't have to fill in anything in the private key box. Plugin deletion worked normally after that.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me too! This error was giving me a headache.

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'DIRECT');
```

to the *wp-config.php* seemed to do the trick for us and updated WordPress to 5.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did you tried `define('FS_METHOD', 'DIRECT');` ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I agree with you @LorenzoDonati. When I replied I clicked to reply, did it wrong, but I didn't cared cause usually StackOVerflow system fixes it. This time it didn't fixed. My bad.